# website visit using python requests doesn't count in google analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests

website visit using python requests doesn't count in google analytics real time

I am using python requests module and google counts the visit but not found in google analytics real time (active users)

my code is below:

```
import requests
import time

agent_android = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': agent_android}


response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: I don't think the requests module would execute javascript code, and without that GA will not track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)
It's perfect for such purposes. Here an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def main():
    url = "https:youURL.com"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(300)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'www.google.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com',
    'Cookie': 'my_cookie=1234567890; another_cookie=abcdefghij'
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print('Failed')
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print('Connection error')
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print('Timeout error')
`
```

Comment: Hi Oscar  Code-only answers are discouraged (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). Good answers tend to have some explanation and some code.