# Python Requests "Show that request has visited website"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

So,
I'm making a request to a website where I have to see one page before another. The first page essentially unlocks the second page. But every time I make a request, on the same IP (I'm using proxies) & User Agent (using `requests.Session()`), it says it's blocked. Now I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563414/website-visit-using-python-requests-doesnt-count-in-google-analytics) thread about selenium. However, using selenium is slow and takes too long to boot up. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
proxies = { 'https' : "proxy" }

headers = {'user-agent': 'USER AGENT'}

s = requests.Session()

glos = s.get("URL1", headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

print(glos.text) # used for debugging to see what page im on

time.sleep(5)

r = s.get("URL2", headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

print(r.text) # used for debugging to see what page im on
```

Comment: Given that the solution in the linked question is helpful, did you try to reverse engineer the javascript?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to.

Comment: The easiest (IMO): in Chrome, open `URL1`, right-click, choose Inspect. There is a source code. Generally, it is known as Chrome developer tools.